# use map function on condition in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of items and I want to edit its values before using it. I am using the `map` function to update each item in it. But the catch here is, I want to only update the items when the list size is 1. I want to return the list as it is if the size is larger than 1. How can I achieve this?

```
myList.map {
      if(resources.getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet) && it.itemList.size<6 && it.layerType == DOUBLE_LIST) {
        it.layerType = SINGLE_LIST_AUTO
        it.itemList.forEach {sectionItem->
          sectionItem.layerType = SINGLE_LIST_AUTO
        }
        it
      }else{
        it
      }
    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just use a simple if statement externally?

Comment: I can but wanted to find a cleaner solution @ChrisvinJem

Comment: Hello, what is `it`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to modify the items in your list only if some conditions are met else return the same list unmodified.

You can consider using takeIf { } for this scenario if you desire to add some syntactic sugar

```
fun updateItemsInMyList(myList:List<SomeClass>): List<SomeClass> {
    return myList
        .takeIf {
            // condition to modify items in your list
            it.size > 1 && otherConditions
        }
        ?.apply {
           //update your items inside the list
        }
        ?: myList // return the unmodified list if conditions are not met
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try using filter before map:

```
.filter { it.itemList.size == 1 }
```

Comment: No. This is not what I am looking for. I want to know the `myList` size instead of `itemList` size before using the map function.

Comment: Ok, in that case just using a simple check should be good. Sorry that i couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if `myList` contains only one value else, you want update the values and return it. You could do something along the following lines,

```
myList.singleOrNull ?: myList.map {
      if(resources.getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet) && it.itemList.size<6 && it.layerType == DOUBLE_LIST) {
        it.layerType = SINGLE_LIST_AUTO
        it.itemList.forEach {sectionItem->
          sectionItem.layerType = SINGLE_LIST_AUTO
        }
        it
      }else{
        it
      }
    }
return myList
```

Basically, check if there's only a single value in the list, if so, then return the value. In the case that there isn't (you get null), then you can map the value.

Comment: `singleOrNull` will return the item. how can I return the same old list?

Comment: My bad, I was supposed to put `return myList` in the end. I honestly wouldn't recommend this solution.

Comment: While it would technically work. You're better off with just using a simple `if (myList.size > 1)`.